# Как конвертировать файл .ui в файл .py?

Tags: python, pyqt5, конвертация

Я знаю способ через pyuic5:

```
$ pyuic5 mydesign.ui -o mydesign.py
```

Но куда его писать? Пробовал в консоль, но выходит ошибка:

```
"$" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: а так пробовали написать в консоли  `pyuic5 mydesign.ui -o mydesign.py`  ?

Comment: Читай вопрос внимательнее

Comment: ArseniyRybasov, это вы сейчас кому написали?

Comment: @S.Nick Извините, не заметил, что вы $ убрали

Comment: Попробовал. Пишет, что нет такого файла или пути. У меня он в папке. Надо указывать полный путь?

Comment: ArseniyRybasov, пожалуйста, будьте внимательны при написании комментариев.

Comment: ArseniyRybasov, в консоли перейдите в папку, в которой у вас лежите `mydesign.ui` , и в этой папке запустите `pyuic5 mydesign.ui -o mydesign.py`

Comment: @S.Nick Это как?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.23586j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8